# MySQL: Slow log; append CPU usage

Tags: mysql, performance, slow-log

I have the MySQL slow log feature enabled: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/slow-query-log.html

But sometimes the query_times are high simply due to high CPU load.

How can I append the current CPU load to each entry in the MySQL slow log (it writes to a file)?

Answer (score 2):

While I don't know of any tool that provides this information specifically, [Percona Server](http://www.percona.com/software/percona-server/) does have a setting ([log_slow_verbosity=full](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-server/5.1/diagnostics/slow_extended.html?id=percona-server%3afeatures%3aslow_extended_51&redirect=2)) that enables extended statisitics in the slow log along with microsecond granularity.  The data does not explicitly include CPU utilization, but it does provide a number of additional statistics about the internals of MySQL and InnoDB that may help you determine whether or not the problem is CPU related or a result of poor optimization.

This is an example of the additional information in the slow log:

```
# Time: 120114  6:34:33
# User@Host: user[user] @  [10.10.10.10]
# Thread_id: 28313080  Schema: mydb  Last_errno: 0  Killed: 0
# Query_time: 0.588882  Lock_time: 0.000068  Rows_sent: 3  Rows_examined: 183839  Rows_affected: 0  Rows_read: 100
# Bytes_sent: 121  Tmp_tables: 0  Tmp_disk_tables: 0  Tmp_table_sizes: 0
# InnoDB_trx_id: 9903E4DB1
# QC_Hit: No  Full_scan: No  Full_join: No  Tmp_table: No  Tmp_table_on_disk: No
# Filesort: No  Filesort_on_disk: No  Merge_passes: 0
#   InnoDB_IO_r_ops: 0  InnoDB_IO_r_bytes: 0  InnoDB_IO_r_wait: 0.000000
#   InnoDB_rec_lock_wait: 0.000000  InnoDB_queue_wait: 0.000000
#   InnoDB_pages_distinct: 11359
```

Also, [pt-query-digest](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.0/pt-query-digest.html) from the [Percona Toolkit](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.0/) understands this additional information and will summarize the slow query log for you and produce output, per query, that looks like this:

```
# Query 1: 0.09 QPS, 0.07x concurrency, ID 0x20112A1CCDBDBA4E at byte 4337645
# Scores: Apdex = 1.00 [1.0], V/M = 0.01
# Query_time sparkline: |     ^  |
# Time range: 2012-01-14 06:34:33 to 08:51:57
# Attribute    pct   total     min     max     avg     95%  stddev  median
# ============ === ======= ======= ======= ======= ======= ======= =======
# Count         63     775
# Exec time     59    539s   522ms   855ms   695ms   816ms    87ms   640ms
# Lock time     18    60ms    43us   498us    76us   103us    36us    66us
# Rows sent      1   3.15k       0      38    4.17   12.54    4.90    2.90
# Rows examine  22 135.93M 179.38k 179.90k 179.60k 174.27k       0 174.27k
# Rows affecte   0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
# Rows read      0   3.43k       0     118    4.53   20.43   11.93    0.99
# Bytes sent     1 103.07k      82     576  136.18  246.02   63.85  118.34
# Merge passes   0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
# Tmp tables     0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
# Tmp disk tbl   0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
# Tmp tbl size   0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
# Query size     5 222.51k     294     294     294     294       0     294
# InnoDB:
# IO r bytes     0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
# IO r ops       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
# IO r wait      0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
# pages distin  63   8.44M  10.66k  12.72k  11.15k  11.34k  357.67  10.80k
# queue wait     0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
# rec lock wai   0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
# String:
# Databases    mydb
# Hosts
# InnoDB trxID 9903E4DB1 (1/0%), 9903E4E09 (1/0%)... 773 more
# Last errno   0
# Users        user
# Query_time distribution
#   1us
#  10us
# 100us
#   1ms
#  10ms
# 100ms  ################################################################
#    1s
#  10s+
# Tables
#    SHOW TABLE STATUS FROM `mydb` LIKE 'table'\G
#    SHOW CREATE TABLE `mydb`.`table`\G
# EXPLAIN /*!50100 PARTITIONS*/
```

...followed by the query itself.

I have [blogged](http://insatiabledemand.ideeli.com/post/13508307991/finding-problem-queries-part-1-the-slow-stuff) a bit about using pt-query-digest and other tools for finding performance bottlenecks (and promised more blogging, but haven't gotten around to it yet).

Another tool which may help you is [pt-stalk](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.0/pt-stalk.html) and [pt-collect](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.0/pt-collect.html).  This will allow you to set a threshold based on a running server variable, such as when the number of concurrently running threads jumps up (Threads_running) and then collect a wealth of data about the running system, including cpu, I/O, MySQL statistics, the running processlist, etc to give you the ability to perform a thorough post-mortem.

The additional statistics are only available in Percona Server, but these tools will all work with MySQL GA.

Comment: Ok, I removed it even though I can't think of a use case where Percona Server wouldn't be an improvement over MySQL GA.  I agree that, especially without justification, it doesn't belong in that post, however.

Comment: I agree that pt-stalk/pt-collect will help you identify times of higher-than-normal load. Even if you can't inject that into the slow query, you can use it to cross-reference

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you cannot configure mysql to inject this information for you.  What you could do is setup some other system monitoring such as nagios to independently sample system values such as CPU util and load avgs.  Then you can correlate the graphs with the times of your queries

Comment: I do that already, but the slow log does not occur constantly. It would be far easier and more convenient if I could somehow append the CPU usage into the slow log file.